# Is it possible to use Comparator in the case when I want to compare something depends on it property

Tags: java, compare

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class StatReport{
    private Integer id;
    private Date registrationDate;
    private Map<Currency, BigDecimal> accountMap;

    //Getters, Setters
}
```

I would like to write a method sorts the List depended on the parameter that I pass. For instacnce:

```
public List<StatReport> sortStatReportList(List<StatReport> reports, String propertyName){
    //To sort the reports by propertyName's order. 
}
```

Is the `Comparator<T>` helpful in the case? How can I implement that method in a right way?

Comment: *afaik*, not possible. Perhaps a switch case in comparator and passing  related value to swith helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible  by using [Apache BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html):

```
public List<StatReport> sortStatReportList(List<StatReport> reports, String propertyName){
    List<StatReport> temp = new ArrayList<StatReport>(reports); //create a copy because Collections.sort sorts the given parameter
    Collections.sort(temp , new BeanComparator(propertyName)); 
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm just using apache-commons in the project.

Comment: Every project should use the Apache Commons libraries. $0.02

Comment: Why do you think so? BTW how it's implemented? I mean, how BeanComparator compares my maps or something more strange property type?

Comment: Because it offers very many helpul utility classes for the most common tasks to be executed in a project. Why build new helper methods over and over again( reinvent the wheel) when you can choose to use already existent,tested and bug free libraries such as those provided by Apache.  As for *how it's implemented*, I think, in the end will be calling o1.propertyName.compareTo(o2.propertyName) if no comparator is passed in to contructor.

Comment: That is, there is no problem to sort by the property of Map type (I.e. sort by the map's value).

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection but it would be a bit ugly or you could pass an anonymous class that queries the appropriate field but it would be verbose.

If you are on Java 8 then you can use [the `comparing` comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```
List<StatReport> list = ...;
list.sort(comparing(StatReport::getId)); //to sort on ID
list.sort(comparing(StatReport::getRegistrationDate)); //to sort on registrationDate
```

<sub>Note: you need to `import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;`</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Java 5.

Comment: Then I think the only two alternatives are those described in the first paragraph...

Comment: Might to rewrite an implementation of comparing be a good way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
public class StatReport {

    private Integer id;
    private Date registrationDate;
    private Map<Currency, BigDecimal> accountMap;

    //Getters, Setters
}

enum ReportComparator {

    ByID {

                @Override
                Comparator<StatReport> get() {
                    return new Comparator<StatReport>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(StatReport o1, StatReport o2) {
                            return o1.id.compareTo(o2.id);
                        }

                    };
                }
            },
    ByRegistrationDate {

                @Override
                Comparator<StatReport> get() {
                    return new Comparator<StatReport>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(StatReport o1, StatReport o2) {
                            return o1.registrationDate.compareTo(o2.registrationDate);
                        }

                    };
                }
            };

    abstract Comparator<StatReport> get();
}

public void test() {
    List<StatReport> reports = new ArrayList<>();
    // Sort by ID
    reports.sort(ReportComparator.ByID.get());
    // Sort by Date
    reports.sort(ReportComparator.ByRegistrationDate.get());
}
```

If you really need to select the sorting by a `String` then you can use `enum.valueOf(String)` to work out which comparator to use.

Comment: It would be more easy to write a class say `PartnerReportListComparator` and just use `if-else if` clauses. But I think your idea is definitiely useful.